# Добавление пункта в меню загрузки GRUB

Tags: linux, grub

Нужно загрузить программу из *GRUB* с выводом на экран сообщения (например, *"Hello"*).

Знаю, что в файл `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` можно добавить пункт меню. А что там нужно написать, чтобы выводилось сообщение при дальнейшей загрузке?

Answer (score 2):

в принципе, в этот файл (`/etc/grub.d/40_custom`) можно писать всё, что вам нужно добавить в результирующий конфигурационный файл `grub.cfg`. только не удаляйте (а лучше и не модифицируйте) имеющихся в этом файле строк — они необходимы для правильной работы скрипта, собирающего результирующий `grub.cfg`. просто добавьте нужные строки.

например, [`menuentry`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/menuentry.html#menuentry) («пункт меню» в переводе с иностранного).

---

пример загрузки программы `memtest` в 16-битном режиме:

```
menuentry "Memory test" {
  linux16 /memtest86+-5.01.bin
}
```

чтобы после выбора этого пункта меню перед запуском этой программы была выведена информация, можно использовать команду [`echo`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/echo.html#echo):

```
menuentry "Memory test" {
  echo "12345"
  linux16 /memtest86+-5.01.bin
}
```

в данном примере это бесполезно, так как программа `memtest` после запуска полностью «перерисует» весь экран. можно после `echo` добавить команду [`read`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/read.html#read), которая будет бесконечно ожидать нажатия <kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
menuentry "Memory test" {
  linux16 /memtest86+-5.01.bin
  echo "press enter to continue!"
  read
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!:) работает:) а не подскажите, как сделать тоже самое, но сообщение должно выводиться из файла на жестком диске?

Comment: `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` — это «файл на жёстком диске».